# Unable publish app as it is blocked by Alpha testing

Tags: android

Currently, I have a production app, which is using SDK 21.

Since it requires a huge engineering work, to port the app to SDK 23, we make another unstable Alpha release, by using SDK 23

Today, I need to make a critical bug fix release, for our production app.

However, since we have an Alpha app with SDK 23, it prevents us from publishing the new production app, which is using SDK 21.

I try to de-activate Alpha testing, but it just won't help. Please see my screenshot.

[image]

Anything I do, so that I can publish my critical bug fixed production app, with SDK 21?

Thanks.

Comment: Try pushing the app you want in production to Alpha and override the current one? Not ideal, but maybe?

Comment: You are not able to push the new production app to Alpha, as it is having lower SDK version.

Comment: Gotcha, so it isn't even letting you override the existing Alpha app. I thought it was just restricting you from publishing to Beta/Release. What portion of the upgrade to API 23 is so difficult? You could potentially bump your release app but try to modularize the code some so the bump doesn't impact your code so much.

Comment: Upgrade production app to SDK 23 immediately is not an option, as we realize that requires a huge engineering effort (New permission model, most of our custom made UIs break under SDK 23, ...). That's why we spawn another alpha app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get pretty useful advice from [ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake)

> You upload a new prod build to prod (target API 21, higher version
>   than current alpha version number - what you're showing us) and a new
>   alpha build to alpha (target API 23, higher version than new prod
>   build), then publish both simultaneously.
>
> That way alpha users get updated to a new API 23 build and prod users
>   get updated to a new API 21 build and importantly no API 23 using
>   alpha build is offered an API 21 build.

---

> alpha > beta > prod always - remember it is set up so you can promote
>   alpha to prod eventually (which wouldn't work if prod's version number
>   was larger than alpha)

In short, switch to advance mode, upload 2 APKs which targets different SDK. Make sure alpha version code is higher than production version code.

A very lengthy explanation can be found in http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Also, don't forget to click on **deactivate** button, of current alpha and current production before publishing.